# How to get CARTO.js vizjson URL

Tags: carto, carto-js

I am new to CartoDB. I have a free user account with 5 maps. I cannot see CartoDB.js URL just in a publish map. I have got just 'Get the link' and 'Embed it' publish map possibility and not the third one 'CartoDB.js'.

How can I get the vizjson URL also by other maps?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the map you were able to get the vizjson was made by Editor back in the day. Now in BUILDER, the new CARTO UI, there is not an option. Mainly [because BUILDER vizjsons are not fully compatible with the current CARTO.js version (v3.15)](https://carto.com/learn/guides/intro/migrating-from-carto-editor-to-carto-builder#temporary-limitations). A workaround is replicate your map using `createLayer` instead of `createVis`.